# Hibernate @CreationTimestamp @UpdateTimestamp for Calendar

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

In my entity I have fields:

```
@UpdateTimestamp
@Column
private java.util.Calendar modifiedDate;
@CreationTimestamp
@Column
private java.util.Calendar createdDate;
```

These fields are changed by hibernate. I see result saved to DB. In DB saved data without time, how I could explain to hibernate that calendar should be saved with current dateTime?

---

P.S.
I saw workarounds like method annotations `@PreUpdate` `@PrePersist` i do not think i need ones.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the JPA spec regarding the Calendar data type:

> **@Temporal** - This annotation must be specified for persistent fields or properties
>   of type java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar.

In your case you should use:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

for both of the fields.

Another solution would be to simply change from java.util.Calendar to java.sql.Timestamp:

```
@UpdateTimestamp
@Column
private java.sql.Timestamp modifiedDate;
@CreationTimestamp
@Column
private java.sql.Timestamp createdDate;
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp` annotations but you have to specify the TemporalType as a Timestamp.

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "createdDate")
private java.util.Calendar createdDate;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "modifiedDate")
private java.util.Calendar modifiedDate;
```

Otherwise, as you said you can use `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` as follow:

```
@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
  created = Calendar.getInstance();
}

@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdate() {
  updated = Calendar.getInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have considered alternative solution way via spring, it works fine, and easy to shift data in tests. [Original description](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-auditing-part-two/).